# SQL Server to Oracle Datatype conversion

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

What is the equivalent of `nvarchar(max)` from SQL Server in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server's `nvarchar(max)` stores character data of an "unlimited" length.

The equivalent in Oracle would be [`NCLOB`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-AB053D2C-2A40-478E-82E5-B9176C8776FD). Depending on how the database was initialized, `CLOB` might work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

NVARCHAR2(32767) in 12c
 NVARCHAR2(4000) in 11g

Comment: Some explanation would be useful. `NVARCHAR2(32767)` is possible only if you set oracle parameter `MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED`